# How to IP whitelist for a single URL in IIS

Tags: asp.net, whitelist

I have an ASP.NET application that's made up of several .aspx pages. I want one of those .aspx pages to be accessible by only a certain set of IPs. Is this possible?

I know you can IP whitelist at the website level, but can you IP whitelist for a single URL in an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following resource demonstrates how to detect the client IP in ASP.NET:

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/439176-how-get-clients-ip-address-asp-net

Once you have the IP, load your whitelist from the storage mechanism of your choice, perhaps during an Init event (if in a page), and if the IP fails to match, respond like so. (Use `HttpContext.Current.Response` if not in a page.)

```cs
if (!mySafeIpList.Contains(clientIP))
{
    Response.Clear()
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
    Response.End()
}
```

Or, just simply redirect to a valid page:

```cs
Response.Redirect("~/Head-Fake.aspx")
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure you can't do it for a single page via IIS (seek Serverfault.com for more details if you want verification), but if you wanted to do it programmatically, you could hook Application_BeginRequest in your global.asax file. Check the request URL and the request IP address against your restrictions, and only allow the request to continue if they pass.

Comment: +1: for the suggestion to implement the filter in the `Global.asax`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] against your own white list within your app.